# How to change chapter style?

Tags: chapters, overleaf, page, chapter-page

How do i change the chapter style so i get something like this? The font type is not important, but I would like the chapter name below the chapter number.[image]

At this point my code looks like this. Somehow my text will not get under the number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{102, 102, 102}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{112, 154, 184}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB}{229, 208, 146}
\definecolor{col4}{RGB}{213, 151, 80}
\definecolor{col5}{RGB}{66, 51, 63}
\definecolor{col6}{RGB}{180, 104, 84}
\definecolor{col7}{RGB}{215, 208, 198}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{215, 208, 198}

\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\newcommand\CHAP{\fontsize{100}{60}\selectfont}
\newcommand\CHAPTER{\fontsize{48}{60}\selectfont}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\CHAP\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{black}{.}\hsp}{0pt}{\newline\CHAPTER\bfseries}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0mm}{-4mm}{4mm}
\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{4mm}{4mm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0mm}{4mm}{4mm}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%% Chapter page %%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction}\label{Introduction}\noindent
\thispagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtTextLowerLeft{\textcolor{col2}{\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}}}}

% Intro
\noindent
blablablabla

\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: As long as you do not tell us anything about your setup (document class etc) and what you have tried so far, we cannot help much. Additionally note that people generally do not like questions similar to **please do this for me**

Comment: Sorry about that. I am quite new to this. The document class is "report", and I have tried to provide a small piece of code in my post

Comment: Thanks for the edit but please post a *complete* code which we can copy/paste. Right now `color` and `eso-pic` are missing and the color `col2` isn't defined.

Comment: Should be added now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

(1) Using `display` instead of `hang` for the chapter title format.

(2) Expanded background image, wider and taller than the text area.

(3) Smaller dot separation, in `ex` units.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,openany]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{102, 102, 102}
\definecolor{col2}{RGB}{112, 154, 184}
\definecolor{col3}{RGB}{229, 208, 146}
\definecolor{col4}{RGB}{213, 151, 80}
\definecolor{col5}{RGB}{66, 51, 63}
\definecolor{col6}{RGB}{180, 104, 84}
\definecolor{col7}{RGB}{215, 208, 198}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{215, 208, 198}

\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{0.01ex}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand\CHAP{\fontsize{100}{60}\selectfont}
\newcommand\CHAPTER{\fontsize{48}{60}\selectfont}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\CHAP\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{black}{.}\hsp}{0pt}{\CHAPTER\bfseries}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0mm}{-4mm}{4mm}
\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{4mm}{4mm}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0mm}{4mm}{4mm}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% ONLy dummy text <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{document}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%% Chapter page %%%%%%%%%%%%
    \chapter{Introduction}\label{Introduction}\noindent
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\put (1in,1in){\textcolor{col2}{\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2in}{\dimexpr\paperheight-2in}}}} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
    
    % Intro
    \noindent\kant[1]   
    \newpage    

\end{document}
```